# warming up cache using memcached and sorl thumbnail

Tags: python, django, caching, memcached, sorl-thumbnail

I'm new to caching and I've starting using `sorl-thubmnail` along with `memcached`.

I'm creating thumbnails in my template as follows

```
{% thumbnail song.artwork "185x185" crop="center" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

This works fine and creates the thumbnails.

What I want to do is warm the cache beforehand for all the images.

Here is how I'm trying to do that

```
for song in Song.objects.all():
    im = get_thumbnail(song.artwork, '185x185', crop='center', quality=99)
```

This creates the thumbnails in the cache folder but they aren't linked to the image. When I open a page with images on it, it recreates another thumbnail. How can I create thumbnails using the [low level API](http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html#low-level-api-examples) and have it linked to the `Song` object?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work except for the use of different options. As you can read in [the documentation](http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/operation.html) sorl-thumbnail put several options into the hash that goes to be the name of the thumbnail file. In your attached code the extra quality option in the low level code will create a different hash. Thus it should work with:

```
for song in Song.objects.all():
    im = get_thumbnail(song.artwork, '185x185', crop='center')
```